# How to import social network relation csv (dict of list) file into neo4j graph database?

Tags: database, csv, graph, neo4j, social-networking

I have known how to import CSV file into neo4j graph database, but I found that they are all in fix numbers of columns like this:

> id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
>
> id2,id2,id3,id4,id5
>
> id3,id2,id3,id4,id5

But I have a variable columns CSV file describing the relation between person. It looks like this:

> id1,id2,id3,id4,id5
>
> id2,id2,id3,id4,id5, id6, id7
>
> id3,id2,id3

This means that the id1 person follow id2,id3,id4,id5, the id2 person follow id2,id3,id4,id5, id6, id7.

And this file is huge (about 6Gb), how should I import it into neo4j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Here are some hints on how to import using the Cypher `LOAD CSV` clause. To handle truly large data import tasks, you may want to look at the [neo4j-import](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/) tool instead.*

Handling varying numbers of columns is not a problem, since you can treat the each CSV file row as a collection of items.

You should import your data in 2 passes through the CSV file. In the first pass, create all the `Person` nodes. In the second pass, match the appropriate nodes and then create relationships between them. To greatly speed up the second pass, you should first create either an [index](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-schema-index) or a [uniqueness constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-constraints) (which will create an index for you) for matching `Person` nodes by ID.

I will assume that:

- There is one row in your CSV file per `Person`, with the first column of each row having that person's unique ID.
- The row for a `Person` will have only one column if that person does not follow anyone.
- Your neo4j model looks something like this:

  (p1:Person {id: 123})-[:FOLLOWS]->(p2:Person {id: 234})

First, create a uniqueness constraint:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.id IS UNIQUE;
```

Then, create the `Person` nodes using the IDs in the first column of you CSV file. We use `MERGE` to ensure that `LOAD` does not abort (due to the uniqueness constraint) if there happened to be any duplicate IDs in column 1. If you are sure that there are no duplicate IDs, you can use `CREATE` instead, which should be faster. To avoid running out of memory, we process and commit 10000 rows at a time:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///varying.csv" AS row
MERGE (:Person {id: row[0]});
```

Finally, create the relationships between the appropriate `Person` nodes. This query uses `USING INDEX` hints to encourage Cypher to take advantage of the index (automatically created by the uniqueness constraint) to quickly find the appropriate `Person` nodes. Again, to avoid running out of memory, we process 10000 rows at a time:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///varying.csv" AS row
WITH row[0] AS pid1, row[1..] AS followed
UNWIND followed AS pid2
MATCH (p1:Person {id: pid1}), (p2:Person {id: pid2})
USING INDEX p1:Person(id)
USING INDEX p2:Person(id)
MERGE (p1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(p2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your assuming is all right! One more question, I have read the doc of neo4j-import tool, but I still don't know how to import varying numbers of columns CSV through neo4j-import tool. The examples are all about standard CSV file.

Comment: Yes, it might not be possible to use neo4j-import to import CSV files with varying numbers of columns, since that tool relies on a header for each column.

Comment: I successfully import my data using your method, but it's slow. There are about 8 million of nodes and 700 million relations between nodes. It takes about 24 hours but hasn't stopped. My laptop's CPU is intel core i5, and equipped with SSD and 8G memory. It's not a really high-performance machine but I think the progress is too slow.