# Create a social network csv in neo4j / Connections with a timestamp

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher, social-networking

First of, I checked previous questions and found some answers but couldn't transfer the solution to my exact problem. The question which comes the closest to my problem is [this one here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841928/how-to-import-social-network-relation-csv-dict-of-list-file-into-neo4j-graph-d)

**My problem:**

I have a large *.csv* file which contains interactions from different **ids** with a **timestamp**. The columns are *source*, *target* and *servertime* and a row looks like this:

> B_655, B_632, 2020-07-03 00:11:48.828

As the different devices measure the connections in both directions it is common that the same connection but with switched source and target occure at nearly the same time:

> B_632, B_655, 2020-07-03 00:11:47.258

Also the different devices measure every 15s, therefore a longer connection (an interaction which lasted 45s) will have 3 different rows.

> B_655, B_632, 2020-07-03 00:11:48.828
> B_655, B_632, 2020-07-03 00:12:03.828
> B_655, B_632, 2020-07-03 00:12:18.828

I know want to have all of this data in my Neo4j database and have bigger weights on the connections between two ids (source & target) which occured more often, but also be able to investigate the graph with regard to the time. For example I want to query how many new connection id *B_649* had between date X and date y.

**The IDs are unique but as I stated earlier they can appear in the source-column as well as in the target-column.**

In was able to read in the data in neo4J browser but struggled with establishing the connection. A Cypher-Query which worked to read my csv file was as follows:

```html
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///connections.csv' AS row
WITH row.source as sourcetag, datetime(replace(row.servertime, ' ', 'T')) as timestamp, row.target as beacon
RETURN timestamp, sourcetag, beacon
limit 3
```

Does somebody know a way to import such a social-network into neo4j?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to create a unique constraint for the nodes. I will assume that this is a

```
(:User)-[:INTERACTS]->(:User)
```

but you can change it how you see fit later.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.id IS UNIQUE;
```

Now you can go ahead and import the csv file:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///connections.csv' AS row
WITH row.source as sourcetag, 
     datetime(replace(row.servertime, ' ', 'T')) as timestamp, 
     row.target as beacon
MERGE (s:User{id:sourcetag})
MERGE (t:User{id:beacon})
CREATE (s)-[:INTERACTION{date:timestamp}]->(t)
```

You can change the node labels and relationship types how you see fit.

Comment: But I have one subsequent question: For some Node-Node connections there are many edges with different timestamps. I now want to group by these connections and want to have a higher weight on the edge if there are many connections etc. Do you know how such a query would look like?

Comment: Yes, the question is what do you do with timestamps then if you have many connections between a single pair of nodes?

Comment: For simplicity I would just count the timestamps for each connection and not further analysis the specific timestamp for each connection. Therefore between node A and node B would be just one edge with a specific value which represents the amount of total connections with timestamps there are between node A and node B. In a further step I would then analyze the different points in time where the connections appeared.